# The application failed deployment on emulator but the previewer works in Xamarin... I don't know what's wrong?

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

I don't know why I'm getting an error. App is simple welcome to Xamarin label. it shows on previewer....

Installing application on device
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  Deployment failed
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: Exception occurred while executing:
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:338)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:906)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:158)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21328)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3856)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1590)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLite(PackageParser.java:1575)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:331)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  ... 9 more
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00173] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-0/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:345 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-0/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:753 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in :0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-08/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2343 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: Unexpected install output: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: Exception occurred while executing:
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:338)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:906)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:158)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21328)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3856)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1590)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLite(PackageParser.java:1575)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:331)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  ... 9 more
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00173] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-0/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:345 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-0/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:753 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in :0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-08/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2343 
Done building target "_Upload" in project "deleteme.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "deleteme.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  Deployment failed
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: Exception occurred while executing:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:338)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:906)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:158)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21328)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3856)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1590)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLite(PackageParser.java:1575)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:331)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  ... 9 more
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00173] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-0/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:345 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-0/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:753 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in :0 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-08/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2343 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: Unexpected install output: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: Exception occurred while executing:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:338)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:906)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:158)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21328)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3856)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1590)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLite(PackageParser.java:1575)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:331)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:  ... 9 more
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00173] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-0/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:345 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-0/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:753 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in :0 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-08/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2343 
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:19.72
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  Deployment failed
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: Exception occurred while executing:
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:338)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:906)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:158)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21328)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3856)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1590)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLite(PackageParser.java:1575)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:331)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:  ... 9 more
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00173] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-0/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:345 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/monodroid-multibranch_d16-0/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:753 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in :0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0000:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-08/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2343 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: Unexpected install output: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/com.buckangoapps.deleteme-Signed.apk
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(615,2): error ADB0010: 
    2 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:19.72

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing SIGNED App , be sure that:

- First, Uninstall the installed previous App from phone.
- Second, Reinstall the App.

Comment: @hypnocool Okey, do you have a device log, this will be helpful to analyse where problem is.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#device-deployment-logs